# Class template argument deduction fails leads to substitution failure

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-deduction

I have a simple program that I am attempting to use to test C++17's class template argument deduction.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const char* a = "Hello";
    std::list x(1, a);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to std::list to deduce the list having type `const char*`. However when attempting to run this code I obtain the error `No viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'list'`. Specifically the constructor that should be matched to this `list(size_type __n, const value_type& __x);` reports an error saying:

`Candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Tp = const char *, _Alloc = std::__1::allocator<const char *>]: 'size_type' is a protected member of 'std::__1::__list_imp<const char *, std::__1::allocator<const char *> >'`

I am curious why this does not work and yet a program like this is completely well formed with `std::pair` able to easily deduce the arguments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const char* a = "Hello";
    std::pair x(1, a);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The `explicit` on the constructor probably makes a difference.

Comment: @Eljay but the constructor is not marked explicit in the header

Comment: Ahh, yes, that was pre C++11.  My mistake.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I couldn't reproduce with any of recent gcc, clang and vc.

Comment: @AntonSavin I am using clang++ on MacOS.

Comment: This worked for me, `auto x = std::list{a};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clang 5 and 6 and gcc 7 and 8 compile your code without problem. So you are using either a compiler that didn't implement correctly the deduction guides or a library that doesn't have the appropriate deduction guides for `std::list`

Comment: I am using clang++ on a Mac.

Comment: @RaeesRajwani which version? And are you linking against libstdc++ or libc++ ?

Comment: I am linking against libc++. The command I use to compile is: clang++ -Wall -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -O3

Comment: It seems that linking against libstdc++ fixes the issue. It does seem like this is an issue stemming from incomplete implementation of libc++ on MacOS. Thank you